# Maximizing slow multi-parameter function

Tags: optimization

What's the best method to maximize the value of slow multivariate function? Here is what I know about the function:

1. Number of parameters is ~ 10.
2. It takes considerable amount of time to compute the value of the function for single variable set. Let's say 30 minutes.
3. Function seems to be concave against every individual parameter.
4. I can run computation in parallel.

All my code is in Java and I'm interested in coding crude version of the optimization algorithm myself rather than using some industry solver.

Comment: Here's a related question I posted a while back, but most of the answers were about existing packages: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10068/global-maximization-of-expensive-objective-function

Comment: If you can do computations in parallel then scan parameters and generate a look-up table of values; then use the table and interpolation to solve the optimization problem.

Comment: What does "slow multivariate function" mean?

Comment: slow multivariate function - `f(x1, x2, x3, ...)` that takes a long time to compute, e.g. 30 minutes. To contrast here is fast multivariate function: `f(x, y, z) = x + y * z^2`

Comment: Any clue why the function is this slow? I.e., are you doing shape optimization in a large-scale 3D PDE problem or is the code just lousy?

Comment: You say that the function you're maximizing appears to be convex, which is the hard case.  Did you actually mean that the function is concave?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: you are right, I meant concave.

Comment: @BillBarth: The function is a result of backtest-like simulation over temporal data. Thinks stock prices.

Comment: Are your objective function values computed precisely, or is there some randomness inherent in the evaluation of the function by simulation?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Objective function is precise, i.e. no error term present

Comment: Do you know whether your objective function is smooth (differentiable), whether or not you have any way to compute the derivatives?

Comment: If you look at it real close then it will probably look like a step function. But the steps are quite narrow, and within the parameter ranges of interest it *looks* quite smooth, but there is no way to calculate derivatives.

Comment: If the underlying function is reasonably smooth, then finite difference derivative approximations can be effective.  If the underlying function is inherently non-smooth, then you don't want to use any optimization method that assumes smoothness.  It sounds as though you could get away with finite difference approximations to the gradient (with 10 parameters, you can get a finite difference gradient with 11 function evaluations in paralllel.)